# Replace a value of a data in a array (React Js)

Tags: reactjs

I have a object called mcqData, in it there is a data called selectedAnswer which is set to null by default. My objective is to give value for the selectedAnswer when every i select a value from the answer radio button.

Below shown is the mcqData object,

```
const mcqData = [
  {
    id: 0,
    question: "What is a variable in software software programming?",
    score: "Score 3 XP",
    answers: [
      {
        id: 0,
        answer: "Value that automatically vary"
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        answer: "A command to run your program"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        answer: "Memory location to store some value"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        answer: "None of the above"
      }
    ],
    correctAnswer: "Value that automatically vary",
    selectedAnswer: null
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    question: "What is the answer to this expression, 22 % 3 is?",
    score: "Score 5 XP",
    answers: [
      {
        id: 0,
        answer: "7"
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        answer: "5"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        answer: "0"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        answer: "1"
      }
    ],
    correctAnswer: "5",
    selectedAnswer: null
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    question: "Which of the following will run without errors?",
    score: "Score 5 XP",
    answers: [
      {
        id: 0,
        answer: "7"
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        answer: "5"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        answer: "0"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        answer: "1"
      }
    ],
    correctAnswer: "0",
    selectedAnswer: null
  }
];
```

This is the code for my radio button with answers,

```
<div className="ml-14 space-y-2">
  {mcq.answers.map(answer => (
  <div key={answer.id} className="space-x-2">
    <input className="mqc-radio-botton cursor-pointer" type="radio" name={'action' + mcq.id} id={answer.id.toString()} // checked={answer1==='answer1' } value={answer.answer} onChange={e=> {
    mcq.selectedAnswer =
    e.target.value;
    }}
    />
    <label htmlFor={answer.id.toString()} className="pl-2.5">
      {answer.answer}
    </label>
  </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

The way iam assigning `mcq.selectedAnswer = e.target.value;` it is only temporarily getting assigned. I want to set it to a state which will assign the value to selectedAnswer permenantly.

My idea is to use a new state with the assigned value, can anyone help me how i can assign a state with the value(this is a functional component)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Whats `mcq`? Can u add a working code of it.

Comment: try to save data in local storage

Comment: what do you mean by `permenantly`? you mean when user refresh the page, you keep the answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample based on your JSON.

For the permanent storage in the same machine(Even if the user refreshes the screen) I am using local storage.

```
export default function App() {
  const [mcq, setMcq] = useState(mcqData);
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("myData", JSON.stringify(mcq));
  }, [mcq]);
  return (
    <div className="ml-14 space-y-2">
      {mcq.map((question, qindex) => {
        return (
          <div>
            {question.id} : {question.question}
            <div>
              {question.answers.map((answer, aIndex) => (
                <div key={answer.id} className="space-x-2">
                  <input
                    className="mqc-radio-botton cursor-pointer"
                    type="radio"
                    // name={'action' + mcq.id}
                    id={answer.id.toString()}
                    checked={question.selectedAnswer === answer}
                    // value={answer.answer}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      let prevState = [...mcq];
                      prevState[qindex].selectedAnswer = answer;
                      setMcq(prevState);
                    }}
                  />
                  <label htmlFor={answer.id.toString()} className="pl-2.5">
                    {answer.answer}
                  </label>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working example link

https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-carlos-how61?file=/src/App.js